# Zero value MenuItem in a Material-UI SelectField with Redux-Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm using a Material-UI `SelectField` to choose the age. For infants, this means there's a `MenuItem` with `value={0}` and `key={0}`. Problem: the zero is not displayed in the `MenuItem`:

[image]

And it seems that the Redux Form is also left without a value, because the `required` validation is triggered:

[image]

Even more strange, I internationalized the values with `react-intl`:

```
  listAges = (personType, ageFrom, ageTo ) => {
    var items = [];
    _.range(ageFrom.get(personType.code), ageTo.get(personType.code)).forEach(function(age) {
      var text = <FormattedMessage
                    id="personType.years"
                    defaultMessage={`{ age, plural, =0 {{age} años} one {{age} año} other {{age} años} } `}
                    values={{ age: age }}
                />
      items.push(<MenuItem key={age} value={age} primaryText={text}/>);
    });

    return items;
  }
```

And the zero is still not displayed:

[image]

In the [Material-UI demos](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) (the Long Example), everything seems to work fine with a zero value. I'm using `redux-form-material-ui`. Could it be a `redux-form` problem?

I'm using the latest version of these libraries:

```
"material-ui": "^0.16.4",
"react-intl": "^2.2.3",
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-form": "^6.2.1",
"redux-form-material-ui": "^4.1.2",
```

Any ideas / workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your problem is not with `material-ui`, but something with your `age` variable or `FormattedMessage` (maybe `age` is null and being formatted as empty string). Here is a basic example that uses zero for `key` and `value` without a problem:

```
class SelectFieldExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    const items = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      items.push(
        <MenuItem value={i} key={i} primaryText={`${i} años`} />
      );
    };

    return (
      <SelectField value={this.state.value} onChange={(e, i, v) => this.setState({ value: v }) }>
        {items}
      </SelectField>  
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, as I pointed out in the question, looking at the Material-UI example, it's clear that it's probably not their fault. I doubt it has to do with the age variable, as all the other numbers work fine, and the same goes for FormattedMessage (the behaviour was exactly the same before I used it). So I guess it must be a redux-form problem, but that doesn't help me much for now :)